# Locating all numbers not present in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am having difficulties trying to locate multiple values from columns in a csv file.

So far i have tried defining the columns from which i want to extract the values as,

```
Assignments = (data.loc[:, ~data.columns.isin(['A', 'B','C'])])
```

This should take each column not named 'A', 'B' of 'C' from the csv file.

I tried running the code,

```
data.loc[(data[Assignments] != 20)]
```

but i am met with the error message: # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 100

The wanted outcome is a list of all rows that don't contain the value 20 (I am also not sure how to add more values than one like for example != 20,10,0.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single value, you can do: `df[(df[:] != 20).all(axis = 1)]`

For multiple values you can use numpy arrays to do elementwise boolean logic:

```
ar1 = np.array((df[:] != 20).all(axis = 1))
ar2 = np.array((df[:] != 30).all(axis = 1))
df[ar1 & ar2]
```

Comment: Welcome, you can accept the answer so others know it's solved. Good luck!